# Как отправить от сервера к клиенту о завершений работы?

Tags: python-3.x, сервер, сокет

Как отправить от сервера к клиенту  о завершений работы ?

у меня получилось но завершается только сервер а клиент продолжает работать

код:

```
import socket
import argparse
import sys
import threading

args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args.add_argument('-p','--port', type=int, help='port',metavar='')
args = args.parse_args()

def server(port):
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port))
    print("Server started your ip",socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()),"\n")
    sock.listen(3)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print("Connected",addr)

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data == "exit":
            conn.send('end'.encode())
            break
        if not data:
            conn.send("\n".encode())
        print("Server",data.decode())


def client():
    console = input('~ ')
    array = console.split()
    sock = socket.socket()
    if array[0] == 'connect':
        try:
            input_port = int(array[2])
            sock.connect((array[1], input_port))
        except:
            print("Your don't write port")
            return client()
    elif array[0] == 'exit':
        return SystemExit
    else:
        print('Error command')
        return client()
    while 1:
        stdin = ''
        while not stdin:
            sock.send(input('>').encode())
        if sock.recv(1024).decode() == "end":
            conn.close()


p1 = threading.Thread(target=server, name="t1", args=[args.port])   
p2 = threading.Thread(target=client, name="t2")


p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Comment: Просто выходите из цикла у клиента. А зачем у вас цикл `while not stdin:`? `stdin` судя по коду никогда не меняется, соответственно, цикл не завершается

Comment: @gil9red цикл `while not stdin:` для того чтобы я смог отправлять пустые сообщения

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, решение в ответе :)